# Sort an array of objects in ascending order but put all zeros at the end

Tags: javascript

If I have an array of objects:

```
[{
    val: 0
}, {
    val: 1
}, {
    val: 0
}, {
    val: 3
}]
```

How can I sort it in ascending order, but keep the zeros at the end, like this:

```
[{val:1}, {val:3}, {val: 0},{val: 0}]
```

Sorting, as expected, puts zeros on the top. Even if I add logic to sort zeros towards the end:

```
array.sort((a,b) => {
    if (a.val === 0 || b.val === 0) return 1;
    return a.val < b.val;
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `a.val` is 0, return `1`. If `b.val` is 0, return `-1`

```js
var array = [{val: 0}, {val: 1}, {val: 0}, {val: 3}];

array.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.val === 0) return 1;        //Return 1 so that b goes first
  if (b.val === 0) return -1;       //Return -1 so that a goes first
  return a.val - b.val;
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could check for zero and move this values to bottom, then sort by value.

```js
var array = [{ val: 0 }, { val: 1 }, { val: 0 }, { val: 3 }];

array.sort((a, b) => (a.val === 0) - (b.val === 0) || a.val - b.val);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply filter out zero and non-zero array, sort non zero array and concat both.

Try the following:

```js
var arr = [{
    val: 0
}, {
    val: 1
}, {
    val: 0
}, {
    val: 3
}];
var nonZero = arr.filter((a)=>a.val !== 0);
var zeroArray = arr.filter((a)=>a.val === 0);
nonZero.sort((a,b)=>(a.val -b.val));
arr = nonZero.concat(zeroArray);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the comparator. In case that the element is 0, it will be considered as larger. You cannot return 1 for both a ==0 and b==0.