# Sort JSON entries in a numerical order with specification

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, numeric

I have a JSON, which I successfully can sort numerical.

```
data["example"].sort(function (a, b) {
return a["one"] - b["two"];
});

// Output:
0: {location: "0"}
1: {location: "0"}
2: {location: "0"}
3: {location: "0"}
4: {location: "0"}
5: {location: "0"}
6: {location: "0"}
7: {location: "0"}
8: {location: "1"}
9: {location: "2"}
10: {location: "3"}
11: {location: "4"}
12: {location: "5"}
13: {location: "6"}
14: {location: "7"}
```

However, I want it to sort starting from `1` to `∞`, and after that, append all the `0`'s.

Like this:

```
0: {location: "1"}
1: {location: "2"}
2: {location: "3"}
3: {location: "4"}
4: {location: "5"}
5: {location: "6"}
6: {location: "7"}
7: {location: "0"}
8: {location: "0"}
9: {location: "0"}
10: {location: "0"}
11: {location: "0"}
12: {location: "0"}
13: {location: "0"}
14: {location: "0"}
```

I am sure, there is an easy solution to this, but I can't find anything about that specific numerical sort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Javascript .sort() on an array to put all the zeros at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26006062/using-javascript-sort-on-an-array-to-put-all-the-zeros-at-the-end), or [Sort an array of objects in ascending order but put all zeros at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50933086/215552)

Comment: There is absolutely no JSON in this query. [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if `location` is 0, if it is, use [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity) to sort to make sure all location will be placed in the end of the array.

```js
let arr = [{"location":"0"},{"location":"0"},{"location":"0"},{"location":"0"},{"location":"0"},{"location":"0"},{"location":"0"},{"location":"0"},{"location":"1"},{"location":"2"},{"location":"3"},{"location":"4"},{"location":"5"},{"location":"6"},{"location":"7"}];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (a.location === "0" ? Infinity : a.location) - (b.location === "0" ? Infinity : b.location);
});

console.log(arr);

// Output:
// [{"location":"1"},{"location":"2"},{"location":"3"},{"location":"4"},{"location":"5"},{"location":"6"},{"location":"7"},{"location":"0"},{"location":"0"},{"location":"0"},{"location":"0"},{"location":"0"},{"location":"0"},{"location":"0"},{"location":"0"}];
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

after get output  run for

```
 for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
             array[i].location = i+1;

  }
```

or use map like

```
let counter = 1;
data["example"].sort(function (a, b) {
return a["one"] - b["two"];
}).map(c=> {c.location = counter++;return c});
```